# Why does robocopy use its own command line parser?

Tags: robocopy

If I execute the following command on a Windows 8.1 machine:

```
robocopy "C:\Temp\A\" "C:\Temp\B\"
```

Robocopy fails due to the following problem:

```
Source : C:\Temp\A" C:\Temp\B"\
Dest -

...

ERROR : No Destination Directory Specified.
```

It looks like `\` is used as some kind of escape character (which is not normal behavior in the windows command line) The final `\"` is even transformed to `"\` which I do not understand at all. Why's that so?

Note: this is not the default behavior of the command line, if they would have used `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` within robocopy, they would've retrieved the correct arguments.

Why are they using their own command line parsing? It really confused me for the last hour...

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the trailing backslashes.

From http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html :

> If either the source or destination are a "quoted long foldername" do
>   not include a trailing backslash as this will be treated as an escape
>   character, i.e. "C:\some path\" will fail but "C:\some path\\" or
>   "C:\some path." or "C:\some path" will work.

Comment: Thanks, however, do you know WHY robocopy decided to do this? Does this approach have any advantages for robocopy at all?

Comment: It's not robocopy that's doing this.  It's the default DOS/cmd.exe/cmd.com behavior for passing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy` is not an exception. Any executable uses its own line parser to determine the arguments that were sent to it. The OS just uses the API to create the process and pass to it a string to be handled as arguments. The process can handle the string as it wants.

In the case of `robocopy`, the parser used is the standard Microsoft C startup code. This parser follow the rules described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx), and in the full list you can found

> A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash, \", is interpreted as
>   a literal double quotation mark (").